# Fastest way to turn an Object into an Array

Tags: javascript

I've seen a lot of ways to turn a Javascript object into an array. One thing that I am using is this:

```
shims.values = function (obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    var length = keys.length;
    var values = new Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        values[i] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    return values;
};
```

I know there's nothing like Object.keys (Object.values would be awesome).

Now if I have an Object with thousands of values which I want to turn into an Array, the function above get's a bit slow.

E.g.
Turn this:

```
{
    1: {a:"a"},
    1: {b:"b"},
    ....
    1000000: {c:"c"},
}
```

into this:

```
  [{a:"a"},{b:"b"},...,{c:"c"}]
```

Is there a better (faster) way?

Comment: An `Object` with more than one of the same key isn't actually possible. Are the duplicate `1`s just a typo?

Comment: there's no magic method, whatever method used will still need a `for` loop over the thousands items.

Comment: The fastest way is to have what ever made the object in the first place spit out the format you actually need.

Comment: with some of the answers: http://jsperf.com/object-to-array-fastest

Comment: @epoch: some of your tests are flawed because the functions are compiled on each test iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is prolly the shortest & fastest way using pure old js.**

and it's compatible with all browsers.

```
var a=[],b;
for(b in obj){
 a.push(obj[b]);
}
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/B72Sa/

or like @GJK mentioned with newer js versions

```
Array.prototype.slice.call
```

if its a sequential numeric value.

*Note: it depends alot on the keys of the object... you can't sort an object.*

**EDIT - PERFORMANCE**

http://jsperf.com/for-vs-array-proto

**EDIT2**

`hasOwnProperty` is not needed anymore as @Christian is using `Object.keys(obj)` which is part of a newer version of javascript... and in that case prototypes can be defined without beeing enumerable.

example:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj.prototype,'myProto',{value:function(){
 return this; 
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

**EDIT3**

there is nothing faster than plain old javascript.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call
```

means you execute slice than call... so 2 functions... not to talk about how slow `call` is.

then if you also need `Object.keys(obj)` too.... you need to execute another function...

again slower...

so... play with jsperf and test it

Comment: @Christian asked for the fastest way, not the shortest way.  Also, a jsperf.com test might be more pertinent than a fiddle.

Comment: yeah the first example is also prolly the fastest ... cause modern browsers are optimized for push and the vars are cached as you can see. there is no other way to do that..so there is no need to add a i++, i also think that this is faster than Array.prototype.slice.call on simple objects.

Comment: on the other hand, I would expect `push` to be slower than setting a numeric property directly.  In @Christian's shim, the created Array has a predefined length (length of Object.keys), that never needs altering.  In your code, `push` needs to retrieve and update the length property each time it's called.  There may be very little in it and it might all be down to the how the different JavaScript engines optimize `Object.keys`, however.  Please add the OP's code to your performance test, for a better comparison.

Comment: what you expect is not always right. push is optimized... ;) Array.prototype.slice.call == many functions... there is a logic behind that... it's slower... he asked for the fastest code. a simple for in is the fastest....btw it takes alot more time to call slice & call than push.

Comment: play with the code if you want anyone can edit jsperf.

Comment: The first code block in @Christian's question is what you should be comparing to. Also, you may need to add a call to `hasOwnProperty`, which will probably slow your method down quite a bit.

Comment: if someone can use Array.prototype.slice.call then he can also define prototypes that are not enumerable....Object.defineProperty...enumerable:false

Comment: @AndyE–regardless of whether push or direct assignment is used, *length* must be updated unless it is set to `Object.keys(obj).length` to start with. In many modern browsers, *push* is faster than assignment.

Comment: @RobG: that is more or less what I said: *"In \@Christian's shim, the created Array has a predefined length (length of Object.keys), that never needs altering."* :-P

Answer (score 2):

`Array.slice` works with array-like objects as well as arrays (like `arguments`):

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, 0);
```

EDIT: As Jonathan Lonowski mentioned, the object will need a correct `length` property. If you don't have any other properties in the object, you can just count the keys:

```
obj.length = Object.keys(obj).length;
Array.prototype.slice.call(obj, 0);
```

EDIT2: The jsPerf shows this not being much slower than using a `for` loop. So, not the fastest, but definitely short, and not half bad. :)

Comment: My understanding is that would only work if the objects attributes were numerical? ie. `{0:"a",1:"b"}` etc

Comment: The object will need a `length` property for any `Array` methods to make sense of it. It's not apparent from the question whether it does.

Comment: You're right, I did forget about the `length` property. I'll amend my answer. Shortest way if you know the length. :)

Comment: I doubt this would be any faster if you don't know the length beforehand.  As @JonathanLonowski mentioned, the object needs a `length` property, which would require using Object.keys or a for loop over the properties to get the largest numerical property name.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my post to reflect that. `Object.keys` would definitely be slow, but it would work. You would think that `Array.slice` would be able to just start at 0 and stop when it's missing a number.

Comment: As noted by Jonathan, this will only collect values of properties with numeric names from `0` to `length-1` inclusive (see the algorithm for [slice](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10)). It will also collect values on the prototype chain if they fit the name criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have `object.1` declared twice, which should result in error.

Try using a general foreach loop to iterate over the object and define your new array.

```
var i = 0,
    new_array = [];

for (key in obj) {
    new_array[i] = obj[key];
    i++;
}

console.log(new_array);
```

Comment: Note: It's only an error in strict mode. Otherwise, the last duplicate will just replace the others.

Comment: Thanks. I knew after I wrote that, I was missing something and JS might deal with it silently.

Comment: You should include a *hasOwnProperty* test unless the values of inherited enumerable properties should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is faster, but an alterntive (Smaller) solution could be

```
function obj_to_array(obj){
    var result = [];
    for(var i in obj){ 
        var tmp = {}; 
        tmp[i] = obj[i]; 
        result.push(tmp); 
    }
    return result;
 }
```